# Babel export default function error

Tags: babeljs

I'm writing an application with `resity` and `babel`. In my `route.js`:

```
export default respond = (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('hello');
  next();
}
```

my `index.js`:

```
import restify from 'restify';
import route from './route';

const server = restify.createServer();
server.get('/bonjour', route);

server.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('%s listening at %s', server.name, server.url);
});
```

and my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-2"]
}
```

After compiling, it outputs `route.js`:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

exports.default = respond = function respond(req, res, next) {
  res.send('hello');
  next();
};
```

When I run `node index.js`, I have the following error:

```
exports.default = respond = function respond(req, res, next) {
                          ^

ReferenceError: respond is not defined
```

Could anyone explain why it happened. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to understand what `export default` is. It has two forms:

1. `export default _THING_EVALUATING_TO_VALUE_;`
2. `export default function fn() {}` or `class Name {}`

Since your assignment is not a function or class declaration, you are using the first one, meaning it is a thing that evaluates to a value. And your code does that fine. The issue is that `respond =` is an assignment, and the variable `respond` is not declared anywhere.

So your code would work if you did

```
let respond;
export default respond = (req, res, next) => { }
```

or you can drop the variable assignment and do

```
export default (req, res, next) => { }
```

or you can use a function declaration

```
export default function respond(req, res, next) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I'm working on a react-native project and using the same syntax I did above. It works so I think the module bundler plays a role not just Babel itself in this case.